# Hibernate + Spring: cannot filter lazy loaded collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-session

I'm implementing the soft delete logic for my entities using Spring and Hibernate. I use @Filter Hibernate annotation to perform this logic.
But there is a problem I cannot resolve: the objects in lazy loaded collections are **not** being filtered.

The code is quite simple:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order { 

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "order")
  @Filter(name = "deletedOrderItemFilter", condition = "0 = deleted")
  private Set<OrderItem> orderItems;    

  // getter and setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "order_item")
@FilterDef(name = "deletedOrderItemFilter", defaultCondition = "0 = deleted")
public class OrderItem {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "orderId", nullable = false)
  private Order order;

  @Column(name = "deleted")
  private boolean deleted;

  // getters and setters
}
```

So the logic is "when opening an **Order** object don't show removed **OrderItem**s"
Here is the method in DAO which returns the Session object. The Session factory is Spring's org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.

```
public Session getSession() {
  Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  session.enableFilter("deletedOrderItemFilter");
  return session;
}
```

So this method is being called only explicitly - when I request the List of **Order**s. But what's interesting is that the PersistenceSet for my **orderItems** List seems to have a **null** Session (it's strange 'cause I am not getting any `LazyInitializationException`). So the filter "deletedOrderItemFilter" is not applied to the `orderItems` List.

I've googled it of course and I've found out that as soon as the **Transaction** in which I get the **Order**s List is closed, the **Session** is closed too. But still I cannot find any solution.
I've tried to explicitly assign a new temporary Session to the PersistenceSet (when fetching it) but still no luck (although the session factory seemed to have my filter in the filters list).

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE** OK I can solve it the "dirty" way:

- `OrderItem` implemets my own interface `Removable` with method like `isRemoved`
- in the `orderItems` getter call common filtering method iterating through the items and filtering them.
  The downside is that I would have to load all the objects - deleted and not - from the database.

**UPDATE**
I'm not getting any `LazyInitializationException` because of the sessionFactory Spring bean config property:

```
<prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
```

So I guess: no transaction - no session - no filters applied.

Comment: I'd say it's better to move a deleted row to a new table, like foo_history. This is what Hibernate Envers does.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan thanks, I'll check it out. Actually, I use Envers in my project and maybe it will be enough for my purposes.